# Можно ли сделать команду для перезагрузки бота? discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Можно ли сделать команду, которая будет перезапускать бота? Например я пишу:
+reload, бот перезапускается, также как я бы в VS Code нажал "CTRL + C"?

Answer (score 1):

***Вот код, нужные импорты os, sys***

```
@bot.command()
async def restart(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == ваш айди:
        print("Restarting bot...")
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Перезапуск бота',
            description = f'**Здраствуйте {ctx.author.mention}! Вы как разработчик бота BOT перезапустили его!**',
            color = 0x1abc9c
            )
        await inter.send(embed = embed)
        python = sys.executable
        os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
    else:
        await inter.send('Вы не являетесь разработчиком!')
```